# Grab and display single JSON object in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I did a tutorial and am able to display all of my Articles objects but I cannot figure out how to modify the code in order to grab one specific object and store it in the state. I have tried a lot of different things but I keep getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'.

One note, the id that I am looking for is stored in 'this.props.match.params.id' but I don't really know what this means or how to use it. Thanks

ArticleShow.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getArticle } from "../actions/articleActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class articleShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getArticle();
  }

  render() {
    const { article } = this.props.article;


    return (
      <Container>
        {article.name}
        <br />
        {article.author}
        <br />
        {article.body.split("\r").map((c) => {
          return <p> {c} </p>;
        })}
        <br />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ArticleShow.propTypes = {
  getArticle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  article: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  article: state.article,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getArticle })(ArticleShow);
```

articleActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";

import {
  GET_ARTICLES,
  GET_ARTICLE,
} from "./types";

export const getArticles = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setArticlesLoading());
  axios.get("/api/articles").then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ARTICLES,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};

export const getArticle = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setArticlesLoading());
  axios.get(`/api/articles/${id}`).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ARTICLE,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};
```

articleReducer.js

```
import {
  GET_ARTICLES,
  GET_ARTICLE,
} from "../actions/types";

const intialState = {
  articles: [],
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = intialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ARTICLES:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case GET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        article: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
  default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

routes/api/articles.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// Article Model
const Article = require("../../models/Article");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Article.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then((articles) => res.json(articles));
});

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Article.findById(req.params.id).then((article) => res.json(article));
});

module.exports = router;
```

models/Article.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create schema
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = Article = mongoose.model("article", ArticleSchema);
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: would you be updating the articles node with article data. also, in the articles array, could you share, the representative data that you are sharing

Comment: This is the JSON of all of the Articles objects, of which I am trying to get one by its ID.

```
{"_id":"5f0b628f172467147fbed0c2","name":"Article 4","author":"Carol Henderson","body":"orem Ipsum is simply d,{"_id":"5f0b6208b4841b13d8f08363","name":"Article 3","author":"Joe Smith","body":"orem Ipsum is"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if possible I would suggest you to reconsider how you are storing your data in articles node. In articles array, it would save you lots of complications if you store articles as object instead of array with article id as key if we are updating/deleting/accessing these articles
Secondly, Article should be child component of Articles which would ensure a particular article would always exists when an Article component loads

```
articles: {
  5f0b628f172467147fbed0c2: {
    "name":"Article 4",
    "author":"Carol Henderson"
  }
}
```

In that scenario, your switch block would look like this:

```
case GET_ARTICLES:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: action.payload.reduce((accObj, curObj) => {...accObj, [curObj._id]: curObj}, {}),
        loading: false,
      };
case GET_ARTICLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: {
          [action.payload._id]: action.payload,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
```

But still if you keep it in your current shape due to some use case, you could try this:

```
case GET_ARTICLE:
      // find the article and merge more details
      const article = state.articles.find((art) => art._id === action.payload._id);
      article = {...article, ...action.payload};
      // since state has reference of article via references, your state has now new values.
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
```

I haven't tested the code. But it should give you an idea how to go about it

Comment: It is saying that 'articles' is not defined. is this because that In ArticleShow.js, I have 

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getArticle();
  }

and don't include an ID as an argument? How would I do that?

Comment: my bad. articles is not defined. so you would have to access it as `state.articles`

Comment: I am getting the same error as before, 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' due to the empty articles array.

Comment: do we have articles populated by the time you dispatch getArticle action. If you could share code, that would help me pinpoint.

Comment: No, sorry I didn't specify. The data is coming from MongoDB and the initial state of articles is an empty array. I will put more code up now. Thanks for your time

Comment: 1. ArticleShow component would be rendered by Articles component and it should be visible only when there are non-zero articles.
2. in mapStatetoProps, yo are reading state.article but it should not be that way. Articles component would pass article to ArticleShow component which would now have id that you need to make that api call to pull more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217825/discussion-between-robert-and-ravi-chaudhary).

Comment: joined the chat